# How to set different cache for the same url in litespeed vary cache?

Tags: php, caching, litespeed

In this doc there are only a few descriptions of how to use the vary.

> https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:developer_guide:response_headers

`X-LiteSpeed-Vary: cookie=cookie1,cookie=cookie2`

Is there any more detailed doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://nyphper.wordpress.com/2017/02/23/how-to-use-litespeed-vary-to-generate-different-caches-for-one-page-url-php/

Set `cookie1` to the vary name, when user visits this page, litespeed server will cache the page with the user's cookie `cookie1`'s value. Next time whoever visit this page with the same cookie value will be served the cache